# Should we rename [solvability]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [solvability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solvability), with excerpt:

> A question about how a puzzle can be solved.

However, "solvability" seems to imply that you'd be asking about *whether* a puzzle can be solved. New users especially won't figure this out, and I end up editing this tag into quite a few puzzles where it was missing.

Is this a problem? Should we rename it? (My first idea is [how-to-solve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to-solve), but feel free to suggest others)

Comment: The blurb didn't match the tag wiki, which describes the intended usage of the tag in a way that seems to correspond very well with how the tag is actually used. Fixed the blurb.

Comment: The tag wiki also had "how to solve" in it, as the first item, in fact. Should that be reflected in the excerpt?

Comment: Solvability, as you say in the question above, (and as can be seen from the questions under that tag), is mainly about the "whether", and only in some rare cases about the "how", so if you want to improve the tag, I'd suggest you take the wiki and rewrite it to better reflect that idea.